# Customise app chooser dialog

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an sharing app, where I can share any image files from other apps like Gallery/GooglePhotos.
This I can achieve through

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

When user click the image to share , the app chooser dialog shows all related apps(including my app), which can share.
Is this possible to add a message on that dialog, suggesting user to use my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below code;

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(image_path);
sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: my app is not sending the intent, it's supposed to receive the intent.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your question right, you want to set the title on the chooser that other 3rd party apps open. That's not possible because it's up to those other 3rd party apps to set a title, not yours. Imagine if every app like yours that have sharing capabilities would want to set a different title, what would happen then?

Comment: I was thinking the same, this app chooser is android system dialog, where other apps should not have hold on this.